Settings->Bluetooth shows devices Disconnected even though they are working. How to fix?
This is in 24.10. When I go to Settings->Bluetooth, I see both of my Bluetooth devices, a mouse (Logitech M535) and a keyboard (Logitech K480). But they both say "Disconnected" even though they are actually working, so obviously connected. If I click on one of the devices, the Connection toggle is in the off position. If I try to turn it on, it tries for about 3 sec and then gives up. Is there any way to fix this? Obviously not a show-stopper, but something is clearly broken.

Fixed by telling it to "forget" the device, then re-pair (repeat setup). To do this for the mouse, it is necessary to have a non-bluetooth mouse available. Did this for both devices. Now they show up as "Connected".
